# How to get raw data from serial port device into android tablet

Tags: android

I have a android tablet, i need to read raw data from any device(which supports rs 232) into my android tablet and display it in a rich text box inside my app.  My android device should act as the host.

Thanks

Comment: Related / duplicate of: "[RS232 Serial Communication with Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26464320)". A good answer is over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://blog.350nice.com/wp/
```

managed to run the ADK in an Arduino with a USB Host Shield controlling a servo or LED

im posting some good links u can refer..i personally found interesting..

http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/wiki/android_to_rs232_guideline

http://sven.killig.de/android/N1/2.2/usb_host/

http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/10/google-announces-android-open-accessory-standard-arduino-based/

http://www.arduino.cc/

http://blog.makezine.com/2011/06/19/adventures-in-android-adk-development-hardware/

You need to get "FlexSerial" cable., getting the Tab to communicate with the RS232 cables in the right way may be tricky. The flex serial cable is certainly a start but the function you are looking for is probably very specific to the device you want to control so finding the right Android app will not be easy. Just out of curiousity, what device is it?

Comment: thanks ashish.n. It may be any machinery used in small scale industry.